# Replace a pattern in CSV file with newline character

Tags: csv, powershell

I have a CSV file where the data is showing in one line. I need to replace a pattern (e.g. ,END,) with newline so that I can see the data in multiple records and load it through Informatica.

I tried following the PowerShell command :

```
powershell -Command "( gc <path>\filename.csv) -replace ',END,', '`n`r' | Out-File  -encoding ASCII <path>\filename.csv".
```

Tried few option like `\r\n` etc. also in the above command.Generated file showing new replaced character `` `n`r `` instead of creating the file with multiple record when I open using notepad++/notepad.Solution in batch file or PowerShell will do.

Answer (score 0):

Variables do not expand in single quotes. The character sequences are also backwards. That might not be important in every instance as many modern programs can work around it but should be done properly.

```
powershell -Command "(Get-Content <path>\filename.csv) -replace ',END,', "`r`n" | Set-Content <path>\filename.csv".
```

`Set-Content` defaults to ASCII encoding so you don't *need* `Out-File`

Answer (score 0):

If the size of the file is smaller use Delimiter feature with Get-Content

Get-Content -Delimiter "END" -Path /file

Above command breaks your file into lines however you'd need to replace END with "" subsequently.